# Notification when full power

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-surface

Is there a way I can get a notification to appear when my battery on my laptop is at 100%. I have a Surface Pro 3 with windows 8.1. I am needing to know this so i can unplug the charger when it is fully charges and so i do not wear out the battery.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center. To be more specific: SuperUser is not about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,

Comment: @LPChip [Allow appropriate tablet questions](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5047/337631) suggests the communiity has voted for appropriate table questions to be on topic. Perhaps you should raise this on meta for an update?

Comment: You want a notification... this means you have to see the screen. If you can see the screen, why not look at the power icon to see?

Comment: @DavidPostill ah thanks. Was unaware of this. That decision was made before I became active on SU. Replied a comment there.

Comment: @LPChip I would raise a new meta question ... as the linked one is so old. And I don't think a comment is enough to bump the question. You can of course undo your close vote.

Comment: @LPChip I wasn't aware of it either. I just thought I would double check and sreach meta ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill ah, good call. Yeah, maybe a new meta question would work. I'm not really active on meta though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a to get a notification when a laptop battery is 100% charged?

The script below should do what you want with some appropriate tweaking.

> Save below as battery.vbs and put a shortcut to "wscript
> path-to\battery.vbs" in your startup folder.
>
> ```
> set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
> set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
> set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")
> for each oResult in oResults
>    iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
> next
>
> while (1)
>   set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
>   for each oResult in oResults
>     iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
>     bCharging = oResult.Charging
>   next
>   iPercent = ((iRemaining / iFull) * 100) mod 100
>   if bCharging and (iPercent > 95) Then msgbox "Battery is at " & iPercent & "%",vbInformation, "Battery monitor"
>   wscript.sleep 30000 ' 5 minutes
> wend
> ```

Source [Get an alert when my battery reaches 95%](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2013/04/24/get-an-alert-when-my-battery-reaches-95.aspx)

Comment: Whilst this doesn't mean the user can just walk away (they have to be there when the alert is, which defeats the point really as they can see the charge level)  I think this is probably the best answer. OP does say they want a notification which is... odd  +1

Answer (score 0):

I think David's answer answers your question, but, I'll provide some additional information as I believe this to be relevant and useful.

Lenovo have some software which does what I think you want, called Energy Management.

The recent version allows you to

```
STATEMENT DESCRIPTION:

Comparing with the previous versions, Lenovo Energy Management 6.0 has been improved with the following new features:

1. Add “Battery Level” in Battery Information.

2. Redefine “Battery Health”.

    (1) Change limited capacity of “Best battery heath” to 45%~50% from 80%;

    (2) Detect battery status by hardware automatically;

    (3) Pop up a hint box to suggest users to switch the mode;

3. Add hint when using unauthorized battery.

4. Remove the scheme of “Power Saver”.

5. Remove “Advanced Settings” of “Super Energy Saver”.
```

[Source](http://support.lenovo.com/ae/ar/documents/ht034410)

There is a [review](http://www.bestcomputersreview.com/lenovo/lenovo-energy-management-for-surface-2.html) of an older version working with the Surface 2 which suggests it will work with the Surface 3

However, this post on SuperUser suggests other wise (again for Surface Pro) - [How can I limit battery charging on a Surface Pro (2) or Windows 8(.1)?](https://superuser.com/questions/664585/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-on-a-surface-pro-2-or-windows-8-1)