# How can I command my Lenovo laptop to stop charging the battery at a maximum cap of my choice?

Tags: battery

[Other laptop brands](https://superuser.com/q/502328) like [Asus](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1032726/) allow you multiple choices of the maximum battery level when your battery stops charging, like  80% or 50%. But my Lenovo laptop doesn't, and proffers just 55-60%.

How can I enjoin my Lenovo laptop to stop charging

1. when the battery attains 80% of my choice?
2. at a maximum cap of my choice?

[image]

[BU-808: How to Prolong Lithium-based Batteries - Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries)

> To make this feature user-friendly, a device should feature a “Long Life” mode that keeps the battery at 4.05V/cell and offers a SoC of about 80 percent.

Comment: Which Lenovo laptop model do you own?

Comment: You may not be able to select the exact figures. I recently dealt with an 11 inch Lenovo laptop where it was  a choice of 80% or 100% and required Lenovo software - which, coming from a Dell World surprised me (Dell lets you set whatever you like in BIOS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I enjoin my Lenovo laptop to stop charging
>
> when the battery attains 80% of my choice?
>
> at a maximum cap of my choice?

It may depend on the BIOS and Power Management for your laptop.

Also, for a laptop always plugged in, the general rule of thumb for a Lithium Ion battery is 80 %.  I use 80% for both my Lenovo ThinkPads.

Use Lenovo Vantage to set your battery. Get Vantage from the Microsoft Store.

Use the Power Menu under Device Settings from the hamburger icon top right.

Then you can set the charging threshold.  You may need to reset the battery for charge threshold to work.

[image: Lenovo Charge Threshold]

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the Lenovo Energy Management tool. It has a "[battery protection mode](https://cdn.lo4d.com/t/screenshot/800/lenovo-energy-management.jpg)" or you can ask it to optimize for "[maximum battery life or optimized battery health](https://bloatwareremover.com/removal-guides/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/energy-management.png)".

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ChargeThreshold.exe (127kB) command line utility to set the charging limits instead of the Lenovo Vantage bloatware's half GB.

For details and download location, see: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Vantage-Knowledge-Base/Q-amp-A-setting-a-ThinkPad-battery-charge-threshold-by-script/ta-p/4345631

Worked on my P16s with Win 11.